# Issues with addRole to user when hitting a certain level

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to add a function to my discord bot `xp-system` by adding a user automatically to a role when hitting a certain level.

I have been trying all kind of solutions I can think of but none seem to work.

Have tried:

```js
addrankup.addRole(fullmember).catch(console.error);

let addrankup.addRole(fullmember).catch(console.error);

addrankup.addRole(fullmember.id).catch(console.error);
```

Expected when users hit a set level to automatically get the rank:

```js
let xpAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 10;
console.log(xpAdd);

if (!xp[message.author.username]) {
  xp[message.author.username] = {
    xp: 0,
    level: 1
  };
}

let curxp = xp[message.author.username].xp;
let curlvl = xp[message.author.username].level;
let nxtLvl = xp[message.author.username].level * 200;
xp[message.author.username].xp = curxp + xpAdd;
if (nxtLvl <= xp[message.author.username].xp) {
  xp[message.author.username].level = curlvl + 1;

  message.channel.send("Level Up!").then(msg => {
    msg.delete(5000)
  });
}

if (curlvl <= xp[message.author.username].level) {
  xp[message.author.username].level = "2";

  let addrankup = message.mentions.members.first();
  let fullmember = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "Full Member");
  addrankup.addRole(fullmember.id).catch(console.error);
  message.channel.send("You have received a new role!").then(msg => {
    msg.delete(5000)
  });
}

fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

But instead this is what the console tells me:

```
(node:8460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined
  at Client.bot.on (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\index.js:125:15)
  at Client.emit (events.js:187:15)
  at MessageCreateHandler.handle (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
  at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
  at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
  at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
  at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
  at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
  at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:137:47)
  at Receiver.dataMessage (E:\#DeathKillerNOR Discord Bots\DeathKillerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:409:14)
(node:8460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated
either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8460) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that `addrankup` is undefined which in turn means that `message.mentions.members.first();` returns nothing. My guess is that instead of

```
let addrankup = message.mentions.members.first();
```

you're looking for

```
let addrankup = message.member;
```

Comment: ok i changed :

let addrankup = message.mentions.members.first();

to:

let addrankup = message.author;

But now i get another console error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: addrankup.addRole is not a function

Comment: @DeathKillerNOR Sorry I made a little mistake, you can check the updated answer. Instead of `message.author` you'll need `message.member`. Again, sorry for the mistake

Comment: It works. Thank you, this have been a head twister for me for 2 days now. Agein thank you

Comment: @DeathKillerNOR no problem! If this was the solution, please mark the answer as accepted so other user can find it more easily in the future!